# SQL join query and with emtpy fields or with fields containing a text

Tags: sql

im trying to build a select query with fields from two tables and also other fields which do not exist in my DB. E.g. emtpy fields or fields with particular text like 'not available'

for example my query looks like this:

```
select 
Product.id, 
Product.component_number,
Product_discount.price,
from Product
left join Product_discount ON Product_discount.id = Product.id
where 
Product.deleted = 0
```

Now in the same query I want to add fields that do not exist like:

Codenumber >> should always be emtpy

Factor >> should always contain the text 'Yes' for every row

idea is to build a query that is identical to an import file

Thanks...

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: `SELECT blah, '' AS code_number, 'Yes' AS factor, NULL AS null_column FROM blahblah`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select 
       Product.id, 
       Product.component_number,
       Product_discount.price,
       ''    as Codenumber,
       'Yes' as Factor 
  from Product
  left join Product_discount ON Product_discount.id = Product.id
 where Product.deleted = 0;
```

Thank you